# How to use the radio button for dynamic data in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, radio-button, radio-group

I need to take a list of questions from a json file and dynamically allocate them to radio buttons with answer options.

The problem is that whenever I select an option, all the same options as the other questions are selected.

I'm using the ["react-native paper / radio-button-group" lib](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/radio-button-group.html)

Any suggestion?

[image: error example]

```
 <ScrollView ref={scrollRef} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
  <View >
    { questions.map(data =>(
      <View key={data.key} style={{margin:10}}> 
        <Text style={{fontWeight:'bold'}}> 
          {data.quest}
        </Text>
        <RadioButton.Group  onValueChange={newValue => setValue(newValue)} value={value} >
      <View style={styles.radioBtn}>
        <Text>Sempre</Text>
        <RadioButton value={1} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.radioBtn}>
        <Text>Na maioria das vezes</Text>
        <RadioButton value={2} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.radioBtn}>
        <Text>Medianamente</Text>
        <RadioButton value={3} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.radioBtn}>
        <Text>Poucas Vezes</Text>
        <RadioButton value={4} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.radioBtn}>
        <Text>Nunca</Text>
        <RadioButton  value={5} />
      </View>

    </RadioButton.Group>
       </View>
    )) }

   
  </View>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Well, basically, you're giving the same `value` for every question. Just don't. You can seperate them with `data.key` (questions[].key) or any other unique identifier.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

I understand, I tried to make these changes but now it changes the previous states of the button .. Can you show me an example?